# Doctrine not linking to owning object when adding to ArrayCollection

Tags: orm, doctrine, mapping, associations

I have a problem when attempting to create a new `Requirement` object on my website.  In my `Requirement` object I have the following Doctrine field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Verification", mappedBy="requirement", cascade="persist", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $verifications;
```

and I have the following method:

```
public function addVerification($verification) {
    $this->verifications->add($verification);
}
```

In the constructor of the object I initialize the `ArrayCollection`:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->verifications = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

However, when attempting to create a new `Requirement` object everything works fine except that the `Verifications` that are created are not linked to the `Requirement` object.  Both the `Requirement` object and the corresponding `Verification` objects are inserted into the database, but the `requirement_id` field for the `Verification` objects are `NULL`.

Do I need to manually set the `requirement` field in my `Verification` object?  Does Doctrine not do this for me automatically when I use the `add` method for the `ArrayCollection`?

Answer (score 0):

No they arent necessarily updated. If you have bi-directional relationships you must maintain the non-owing side yourself. You can read up on this in the documentation:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html

Its hard for me to give you specifics without seeing both the Requirement and Verification definitions.